# How to distribute apps for testing to Friends without using AppStore

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

I have an app that I want to distribute to my friends - what do I use?

I have an 'Awesome new app' - And I want to distribute to a huge number of people - for testing purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to learn to use [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) and invite your non-developer testers.

Comment: That worked... Thats what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can add UDID for the devices of your friends and then start testing by creating a profile and send ipa to them which can be installed using itunes.